# Need help on calling datas from firebase html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase example:

Users:

- User1

  - A

    - 123
    - 234
    - 345
  - B
  - C

Above is the firebase data.
I wanted to call all the data under User1, A. Which means "123", "234", "345" should be the output for my table. I also wanted to display them to be displayed in a table I have in my html file using javascript. Can anyone advise? I am new to firebase and am confused with the other guides online.

Should I create a table using javascript or keep my table at html file?

Thank you for advise and help.

Comment: Which firebase are you using? Real Time Database or Cloud Firestore?

Comment: @gugateider I am using Real Time database

Answer (score 2):

For Real Time Database try this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/User1/A').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  let items = snapshot.val();
  items.forEach( (v) => writeData(v) );
});
const writeData = (value) => { 
    let el = document.querySelector('p');
    el.innerHTML = value;
    document.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but can u explain the "(v)" on the 3rd line and "innerHTML" on the 7th line. Thank you

Comment: v is the node value from the database, you're passing to writeData function, just console.log(v) so you'll see what its the result

Answer (score 2):

By doing the following, in JavaScript you will get all the children of the User1/A node:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('User1/A');
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    console.log(childKey);
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log(childData);
    //....
  });
});
```

From there you can populate your HTML table

Comment: can this be used with firebase Realtime database?

Comment: Yes, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#once